# Mono on osx seems to ignore #I in compiled source files

Tags: macos, dll, path, f#, mono

I'm battling paths in Fsharp and Mono on OSX. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to make mono follow #I paths in Fsharp?
2. Is some way that I may include the dll in the exe, such that files compiled on one machine may run on another without having to duplicate installation of packages?

Example of the problem is the following: I've installed MathNet.Numerics in a local directory "packages" one level above my source directory using nugget.exe. Running the example:

```
#I "../packages/MathNet.Numerics.3.6.0/lib/net40/"
#r "MathNet.Numerics.dll"
open MathNet.Numerics
let v = SpecialFunctions.Gamma(0.5)
printfn "%g" v
```

followed by ";;" gives

```
...
1.77245
val v : float = 1.772453851
val it : unit = ()
```

while, when placed in the file monoIgnoresPaths.fsx, I have to also tell mono, where the dll is:

```
Solsikke:src sporring$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.12.0 ((detached/a813491 Thu Dec 11 12:24:44 EST 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-(detached/5486eb2)
    GC:            sgen
Solsikke:src sporring$ echo $MONO_PATH 

Solsikke:src sporring$ fsharpc monoIgnoresPaths.fsx 
F# Compiler for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License
Solsikke:src sporring$ mono monoIgnoresPaths.exe 

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MathNet.Numerics, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MathNet.Numerics, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MathNet.Numerics, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MathNet.Numerics, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
Solsikke:src sporring$ export MONO_PATH=`pwd`/../packages/MathNet.Numerics.3.6.0/lib/net40/;
Solsikke:src sporring$ mono monoIgnoresPaths.exe 
1.77245
```

Is this a bug in Mono?

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 1):

`fsharpc` ignores `#I` (by design), the directive is meant to be used only in `fsharpi`.

For your second question, you can use `--standalone` to compile all the references into the binary.